# Netbeans package import Intstream

Tags: java, netbeans

I am new to programming. And i am stuck. I searched online about the netbeans import problem: http://wiki.netbeans.org/Java_EditorUsersGuide#How_to_get_rid_of_unused_imports but it doesn't work

[image: unused import]

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Array {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] a1 = new int [10];
        a1[0]=1;
        Arrays.fill(a1,2);
        System.out.println(a1[0]);
        System.out.println(a1.length);
        String[] a2={"one", "two"};
        int[] oneTo10 = Intstream.rangeClosed(1,10).toArray();

        for(int x: oneTo10) System.out.println(x);

        System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(oneTo10,9));

        int a3[] [] = new int[2][2];
        String[][] a4={{"00","10"},
                {"01","11"}};
        System.out.println(a4[1][1]);

        String a5 [][][]={{{"000"},{"100"},{"200"},{"300"}},
                {{"010"},{"110"},{"210"},{"310"}},
                {{"020"},{"120"},{"220"},{"320"}}};
        System.out.println(a5[2][3][0]);

        int a6[]={1,2,3};
        int a7[] = Arrays.copyOf(a6,3);
        System.out.println(Arrays.equals(a6, a7));
        int a8[] = {3,2,1};
        Arrays.sort(a8);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a8));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in your code.

`int[] oneTo10 = Intstream.rangeClosed(1,10).toArray();`

Its `IntStream` instead `Intstream` (mind small s). It will not report unused import then.

Comment: Thanks @PratapiHermantPatel! I noticed this as well, but you were quicker. I can now delete my answer.